# CancellationTokenSource or AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Modern .NET APIs use CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken for cancelling jobs across threads. Is there any reason to use these instead of the "old" AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent? I imagine that CancellationToken encapsulates something similar, as exposed by its WaitHandle property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476528/stopping-a-thread-manualresetevent-volatile-boolean-or-cancellationtoken)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes. The `CancellationTokenSource` uses a `ManualResetEvent` internally to handle the reporting of the cancellation event.

Still you should prefer to use the `CancellationTokenSource` for cancelling stuff for a couple of reasons:

1. It is right in the name. It cancels stuff. This makes for a easier read since it is clear right from the start what a instance of this class is used for.
2. Many of the classes that are part of the .NET framework and that can be cancelled use the `CancellationTokenSource`. Especially many things in `System.Threading` (and sub-packages)
3. While using a `ManualResetEvent` the `CancellationTokenSource` does a couple of things to optimize things internally. Lazy initialization and such things. I *hope* that makes it just a little faster and run with less overhead under some conditions.

Comment: `ManualResetEvent` is pretty heavy, so it is only created if `CancellationToken.WaitHandle` is used.