# Resume thread after stopping using ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use `ManualResetEvent` to start, pause, resume and terminate thread by referring to [Stopping a Thread, ManualResetEvent, volatile boolean or cancellationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476528/stopping-a-thread-manualresetevent-volatile-boolean-or-cancellationtoken) . I'm confused with `Set()` and `WaitOne()`. Here's my code and I will need some help for the changes that have to be made so that I can resume after pausing the thread and stop entirely then I can start again the work without closing the whole winform.

```
namespace ThreadForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static volatile bool isPausePressed = false;
        private static EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: true);
        Thread SequenceTest = new Thread(DoWork);
        Thread Seq1Test = new Thread(TestSequence1);
        Thread Seq2Test = new Thread(TestSequence2);
        Thread Seq3Test = new Thread(TestSequence3);
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Form2 objform;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objform = new Form2();
            objform.Show();
            var formWithButton = new Form2();
            formWithButton.Btn_Change.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (SequenceTest.IsAlive)
            {
                waitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                SequenceTest.Start();
                Seq1Test.Start();
                Seq2Test.Start();
                Seq3Test.Start();
            }
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isPausePressed = true;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waitHandle.Reset();
            MessageBox.Show("Done!", "ThreadTest");
        }

        public static void DoWork()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("Current main task working on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            while (!isPausePressed)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public static void TestSequence1()
        {
            int i = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sequence1 working on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            while (i!=10)
            {
                i++;
                //Console.WriteLine("Current i value: {0}", i);
            }
            isPausePressed = true;
        }

        public static void TestSequence2()
        {
            int j = 0;
            //Console.WriteLine("Sequence2 working on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            while (j != 10)
            {
                j++;
                //Console.WriteLine("Current j value: {0}", j);
            }
        }

        public static void TestSequence3()
        {
            int k = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sequence3 working on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            while (k != 10)
            {
                k++;
                //Console.WriteLine("Current k value: {0}", k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put event.WaitOne() in the thread logic, the thread will block there if the event isn't set. If the thread is blocked like this you resume it by doing event.Set() from the main thread (or another thread).

Comment: Exactly where should i put all `Set()` `WaitOne()` and `Reset()`. I've read some articles and I'm not sure where to put it. Also, I think that after stopping the thread, restarting it will definitely raise an error.

Comment: To start of you should probably not use a static `ManualResetEvent`. While you can put a `WaitOne()` inside a loop to pause, it is probably not a good design since you will block the thread, unnecessarily consuming resources. You should probably include what it is you are actually trying to do to get better answers.